# How can I get data from a Map on Firebase where the values are 'true'?

Tags: flutter

I have this `Map` `likes` there I use to save the information of people who liked a post.
I save the field with the `id`of each user, and I would like to access this field but only the documents that are `true` and use the `id` to get the users profile. How can I access the `Map` and get the `ids`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to access the list of user ids that are in your `likes` map. In that case, you can do this:

```dart
// Get the post
final DocumentSnapshot post = await Firestore
    .instance
    .collection('posts')
    .document(postId).get(); // Here postId is the id of the post you are accessing

// You can then get the ids list
final ids = post.data['likes'];

// Get the list of ids that has value = true
final userIds = ids.keys.map((e) => ids[e] == true).toList();
```

You can store `likes` as an array instead of Map for convenient data handling, since this `likes` field only store those that liked the post according to the name.

Comment: Thanks Bach, it worked. However I'm getting the ```id: true, id: false``` is it possible to separate this information?

Comment: @RicardoOscarKanitz Edited my answer, please check